# Content of .html file is not displayed when the file extends from another file

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I have an **index.html**, which content I would like to extend to other pages. If I extend **index.html** to **landing-page.html** the content from **index.html** is being displayed, but the content from **landing-page.html** is not.

**Routes.py**

```
@app.route('/welcome/')
def landing_page():
    return render_template('landing-page.html')
```

**landing-page.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>This is from the landing-page</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      {% if title %}
        <title>Test Title - {{ title }}</title>
      {% else %}
        <title>Test Title</title>
      {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>This is from the index page</p>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

When accessing landing-page.html with the route of `/welcome/` this is the output:
[image]

As you can see from the image above, the content of the **landing-page.html** is not displayed. I am unable to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The route /welcome is running properly, but both are not connected.
2 additional things are needed:

1. extend the function (and establish the connection)

```
def landing_page():  
    return render_template('landing-page.html',  
    my_string='FirstInclude')
```

2. place the include at index.html somewhere (and therefor place the connection)

   <p>{{my_string}}</p>